# Humans genetically altered to live underwater after crashing on a planet

Tags: genetic-engineering, story-identification

Trying to find a book where humans were genetically altered to live in water after a crash landing on a planet.  Generations later, they have forgotten they are human.  I think the main character is named Levon and he keep swimming to the surface and dreaming of going to the stars.

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/231352/trying-to-locate-a-sci-fiction-story-about-a-humanoid-micro-sized-in-a-pool (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 27):

James Blish, "[Surface Tension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_Tension_%28short_story%29)", collected in [The Seedling Stars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Seedling_Stars) (and many other places).

Wikipedia summary:

> A human colonization ship crash-lands on a distant planet which is
> earth-like but whose only landmass is completely covered in shallow
> puddles of water and mostly microscope life forms. Normal humans could
> not survive on this planet, so the crew must genetically engineer
> their descendants into something that can survive. (Blish coined the
> term pantropy to refer to this concept.) They decide to create a race
> of microscopic aquatic humanoids to complete their mission and
> colonize the planet.
>
> The majority of the story concerns one group of these genetically
> engineered colonists and their intelligence, curiosity, and evolving
> technology. In particular, the tiny aquatic humanoids develop a "space
> ship", or rather "air ship", which enables them to pierce the
> previously impenetrable surface tension of the water and travel
> through what is, to them, hostile space—open air—to other worlds in
> other puddles of water.

Here's an illustration for the story from the cover of [The Best of James Blish](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?37660).  Nice fig-, erm, algae-leaf!

[image]

The guy's name was actually Lavon.

Comment: ...which is a linguistic shift of the original crashed human's name of La Ventura, if I remember correctly.

The Seedling Stars is an absolutely fantastic collection of pantropy based short stories. One of my favourite books.

Comment: You might be interested in this then: When I was looking for a picture, I ran across this proposed animated film: http://www.pipsqueakfilms.com/home/in-development/surface-tension/